# Jira API issueLink connect two different instances

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

So, I have 2 different instances of Jira (let it be A and B), but they are connected with each other.

I can create manually a link in an issue within A, pointing to an issue within B instance. So, I can track issues from other instances. But how will I do it with an API?

If there will be one instance I will use this: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e5606

Is there a way to determine where it should put the "outward" issue?

Just as an addition - I don't want to use remoteLink, as it's not the same (it's just a raw link and I need a real "connection" with statuses changing).

UPDATE

I have added an answer, example bash script could be seen there

Comment: Create link manually in Jira, then check out how it is done in background by querying those issues through API.

Comment: Did it. It's not shown in json neither from issue dump, nor from get remote links.

Comment: You want to connect from your own app, faking yourself to be another JIRA? Atlassian product do this through the AppLinks JIRA|Confluence|other plugin. Or you want to build the A-B applink automatically by a 3rd party app?

Comment: No, not so complicated. So there is a possibility to connect 2 jira instances databases, so after that it's possible to link one instances issues to another instance issues. I have already did it and it's working perfectly. The problem is when I want to automate such kind of things and it's possible via default jira API. But there is no any documentation how to connect such kind of issues if jira instances are different ones. I can imagine that there should be some extra parameter for telling jira that it should take an issue for linkage not from the current instance, but still can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer.

1) We are making a query to the jira issue which are we going to link (endpoint is /rest/api/latest/issue/${JIRA_ISSUE})

```
curl -D- -u ${JIRA_U}:${JIRA_P} -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -m 60 ${JIRA_SOURCE_LINK}
```

And extracting "id" field. This is the internal id of issue in jira "A"

2) Now we need to post a remote link to jira B '(/rest/api/latest/issue/${JIRA_ISSUE}/remotelink endpoint)' with the knowledge of what is the appId of jira A and what is the internal number of issue from (1) with type "com.atlassian.jira", see "globalId's" "issueId":

```
{
"globalId": "appId=0000-0000-000-000-000&issueId=101",
"application": {
    "type": "com.atlassian.jira",
    "name": "Jira name"
},
"relationship": "relates to",
"object": {
    "url": "https://jiraurl/browse/ISSUE-11",
    "title": "ISSUE-11",
    "icon": {},
    "status": {
        "icon": {}
    }
}
```

}

We will have it like: 
`curl -D- -u ${JIRA_U}:${JIRA_P} -X POST -d '${JSON_TO_POST}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -m 60 ${JIRA_LINK}`

And it's done.

Comment: If somebody has some more answers - feel free to. Just an addition - for me I can't get access to jira database, because I had no needed access, So I took internal id from API.